# Why do I get different charset when python use MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, encode

I wrote a python program use `MySQLdb` in my gentoo:

- mysql version = `5.1.67-log Gentoo Linux mysql-5.1.67`
- characterset  = `utf-8`

when I connect to mysql, and `print conn.character_set_name()`, it returns `utf-8`

But when I test the program in my VPS(ubuntu)

- mysql version = `5.1.60-log Source distribution`
- characterset  = `utf-8`.

and in my program I `print conn.character_set_name()` it returns `latin1`?

Why are the charsets different when use MySQLdb in the two machines?

---

I have read `MySQLdb`'s source code, and it use `_mysql` module, but this is a `.so` file. and I can't know how it to get the `charser`

Comment: It's might be picking up a default charset from the mysql configuration in `/etc/my.cnf` (or wherever it lives on your systems). It's also possible the value is hardcoded into the `mysqld` binary - I vaguely recall there being a `configure` param to set it when I last compiled mysql. It's probably safest just to override the charset when you connect to mysql, then it doesn't matter what the default is.

Comment: @Aya , I connect mysql in command and use `status`, it says all the characterset is `utf-8`. And I just see the `/etc/my.cnf`, there is no options about `charset`.

Comment: @Aya , I have check the my.conf in my local machine. and there is character-set，maybe the mysql in my vps, the charset is hardcoded in the mysqld

Comment: Added an answer with a bit more info. For maximum portability, it's best to always specify the character sets you want to use, then the defaults don't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's worth noting that there are several different character set parameters you can set on mysql...

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

...which can be configured in `my.cnf`, but you generally only need to think about two of them...

1. The character set used when storing data on disk.
2. The character set used in the client/server protocol.

---

The first of these is initially set when you compile mysql, and can be influenced by the [`configure` option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/source-configuration-options.html) [`--with-charset`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/source-configuration-options.html#option_configure_with-charset), which defaults to `latin1` if unspecified.

You can override the default on a per-database basis when creating a database with...

```
CREATE DATABASE my_database CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
```

...or on a per-field basis when creating a table with...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    ...
    my_field VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8',
    ...
);
```

---

As for the second of these, I'm not sure where the default comes from, but you can override it on a per-connection basis with...

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

...or if you're using `MySQLdb`, it's probably best to specify it in the `connect()` settings with...

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='my_host',
                       ...
                       charset='utf8')
```

---

There's a bit more info in the [`MySQLdb` documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html), and it might also be worth taking a look at [section 10.1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset.html) of the MySQL docs.

Comment: Yes, I have check the charset in mysql cmd, and all is `utf-8`, I have check the `my.cnf`, but there is no config about charset, I use `LNMP` one-key install. Maybe as you say, it is hardcode in the it. I think point the charset when connect is a good habit. Thank you!